# Make a pipeline task run after all post-job tasks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline phase with a bunch of tasks, the problem is, azure automatically injects some built-in tasks, one of my tasks will clean up `_work` folder if disk space is low, which once happens, makes all following built-in tasks fail. Is there any way to really move a task at the end of the phase even after all built-in tasks?

[image]

Comment: there is no point in doing that? just make it the last task in your job and that would be it

Comment: Tried that, built-in tasks are always after user tasks, that's the problem :D

Comment: Could you run your clean up task in a separate job or stage?

Comment: thats not a problem, why would it be?

Comment: @Nikola, jobs by default run in parallel, even if i can set job dependencies, according to docs: Each job may use different agents. You should not assume that the state from an earlier job is available during subsequent jobs.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Is there any way to really move a task at the end of the phase even after all built-in tasks?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is by designed and is not a issue.

If this feature/request is important to you, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.